# How to stop my phone from secretly recording me?

Tags: mobile, attack-prevention, audio

I unplug my microphone from my computer when I am not using it. The same with my webcam. I am not using Alexa or similar.

However, my smartphone has an included battery that I cannot take out.

My phone might indicate that it has no wifi connection, but I don't know if it is lying to me.
The same is true with the microphone and camera. I can put stickers over the cameras to make sure they can't secretly record me, but I can't do anything about the microphone. I have to believe what the screen shows. I have even less control over the audio recording devices from the neighboring flats. 
 Who knows which kinds of recording devices THEY have...

What steps can I take to avoid my phone secretly spying on me with my microphone?  Is there anything further I can do to try to avoid other people's devices from secretly recording me?

Comment: Never tried it but there are rumours an external noise-cancelling device can mitigate this.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad so I've edited it to focus it a bit more on securing your own phone, since that is both easier to answer and (from the sounds of it) the part that you are most interested in.  If you don't like my changes then you can always roll back the edit in the edit history.

Comment: As your question is about stopping the non-standard ways that the microphone can be used, you need to understand the operating system of the phone. The duplicate questions will help you work that out. As for how to stop other devices that you do not control or operate, there is little if anything you can do, and it is unrelated to the main question you've asked.

Comment: Quick answer: keep your phone in a box. Set the vibration settings on high so you can hear it buzz when calls come is.

Comment: You might want to watch https://video.vice.com/en_us/video/state-of-surveillance/57582e181c1e5f893ca7f8fb for some ideas.

Comment: @aCVn The video is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your threat model. If you are not a high-value target, then you don't have that much to worry about.

Of course, the best way to prevent someone gathering incriminating evidence on you is to prevent that evidence from being created in the first place. If you have any reason to believe that someone is wiretapping you, don't have any electronic devices near you when you have sensitive conversations. In fact, be careful with sensitive conversations in general. Adversaries can use [lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_microphone) to listen to your conversations, without the need to directly attack your mobile phone.

If you suspect that your neighbor is trying to wiretap you, then hold sensitive conversations outside of your apartment. Your car may be a suitable place, given that it's a moving target. The car of your conversational partner may be an option as well. You will have to weigh how much you trust the Operational Security of your conversational partner, compared to your own.

If this gives you major tinfoil-hat vibes, then you are indeed correct. These approaches are not practical for everyday life, but then again my everyday conversations rarely get more exciting than "Is there anything you need from the grocery store?", so I doubt any Triple-Letter Agency (or MI5) are particularly interested in that.

Comment: When I am at home I just talk to myself sometimes. I do not filter anything. It is my way to stay sane. Yet I have neighbours. And the mentioned smart phone. And windows that could be laser snooped. I do not own a car. I am also sick of having to be careful about what I say. It could be that I said something incriminating then. Who knows, we have a complicated law system in germany. And the state is allowed to spy on people for no reason now. What do you recommend and why?